# What should Authenticate Fetch from a User?

Tags: django, api, performance, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I joined a group that has been using Django and I was just curious for some performance aspects of user fetching for Authentication.

The User objects have some foreignkeys/manytomany fields attached to them. I learned about the prefetch_related / select_related.
So if I want to get everything of a user instance, that would result to about 10 queries.

So my question is about API / REST Design. Should my auth only do 1 Query ( select User) or should it fetch alle the stuff that **could** be useful for other endpoints?

Each endpoint uses the CustomAuthentication, so the queries would be executed for each API call. Is ist better to let people take care of a second well designed query at the endpoint, or should I provide them with alle variables on each endpoint autmatically ?

Thanks in advance.

This question is performance related. I tracked the requests with SILK and was not happy about the performance for retrieving Users

Answer (score 0):

If it is a JWT token-based AuthN, the most recommended approach is to fetch all related data associated with the user and generate the larger JWT token.

However, it is a trade-off. Mainly, related fields are required for Authorization
(AuthZ). If the current system has a handful of API dealing with AuthZ then pulling all related data is costly.

After each API call, pass the JWT token at header and decode it to retrieve the actual payload.

About performance:
Performance highly depends on underlying service (SQL or NoSQL) to persist data. Then the focus area will be on DB optimization (indexing) rather than focusing on frameworks.